# Unindent or linearize XML

Tags: java, xml, text-processing

I'm looking for a fast way to linearize an XML in JAVA

I'm using ~2GB file so DOM is excluded.
Java targhet is 1.5.0.22
I have to generate from an xml a file composed of 80bytes + newline. I have to write this in a DB2 table that will be read by a Cobol program.

In Cobol is important the size because the data are read as CHAR from table this implies the an empty rows is 80 spaces.

I read the file byte to byte(I must) but I can use internal temp bufferization to store the probably sequence to ignore

Example 5 bytes af ascii file

```
<a><b><c>psofpisogiosigpsfiogpo</c></b></a>

<a><b
><c>p
sofpi
sogio
sigps
fiogp
o</c>
</b><
/a>
```

PROBLEM WITH A FILE

```
<a>
    <b>
       <c>psofpisogiosigpsfiogpo</c>
    </b>
</a>







<a>

  <b
>


<c>ps
ofpis
ogios
igpsf
iogpo
</c>

    <
/b>

   </
a>
```

The non linearized XML create empty rows in table or some rows that ar not used to their full potential.

This became a lost of payd cpu cycle unde HOST CICS enviorment

If I can linearize the file i get same output if the file is indented or not and XML keep the same informations

Any Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static final String XML_LINARIZATION_REGEX = "(>|&gt;){1,1}(\\t)*(\\n|\\r)+(\\s)*(<|&lt;){1,1}";

private static final String XML_LINARIZATION_REPLACEMENT = "$1$5";

 public static String linarizeXml(String xml) {
        return (xml!= null) ? xml.trim().replaceAll(XML_LINERIZATION_REGEX, XML_LINERIZATION_REPLACEMENT) : null;
    }
```