# Linearize or unindent XML in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, indentation

I wonder how to linearize or unindent an XML text using Javascript.

This post [Unindent or linearize XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445152/unindent-or-linearize-xml) describes how to do it using Java, but I saw no example using JavaScript.

Comment: The Java example provides a pretty easy to understand implementation. The required regex is available. Have you made an attempt to port the code to JavaScript? share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

As I indicated in the comment on your answer, regex is not a reliable way to do this. A much more reliable approach is to parse the XML, remove any text nodes that are all whitespace, and then re-serialize it:

```js
function parseXml(txt) {
  var parser, xmlDoc;

  if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
  } else // Internet Explorer
  {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
  }

  return xmlDoc;
}

function serializeXml(node) {
  try {
    // XMLSerializer exists in certain browsers
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    return serializer.serializeToString(node);
  } catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer has a different approach to serializing XML
    return elem.xml;
  }

}

function removeWhitespace(node) {
  if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
    Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes).forEach(removeWhitespace);
  }
  if ((node.nodeType === 3 || node.nodeType === 4) && 
      /^[ \r\n\t]*$/.test(node.textContent)) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}

var startXml = '<products>\n\t<product>\n\t\t<code>1234</code>\n\t\t<name>Widget 3000</name>\n\t</product>\n</products>'

console.log('Before:');
console.log(startXml);

var dom = parseXml(startXml);

removeWhitespace(dom);

var endXml = serializeXml(dom);

console.log('After:');
console.log(endXml);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JLRishe, your snippet perfectly works and your approach is adequate.

Answer (score -1):

As [tebs1200](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4501301/tebs1200) suggested, I ported (and even improved) the regular expression from the Java post to Javascript.

Here it is:

```
// This Javascript function is to linearize and return the XML input String
function linearize(xml) {
return (xml!= null) ? xml.trim().replace(/(>|&gt;){1,1}( |\t|\n|\r|\s)*(<|&lt;){1,1}/g, "$1$3") : null;
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely reliable. It will incorrectly remove a space from `<n> Go here -> </n>`, and won't remove whitespace that is encoded as entities (if you need that).